# Making drop-down stay after :hover is no longer active

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar, dropdown

I have a simple navbar with a dropdown menu that is supposed to stay when a user hovers over its respected link in the navbar but I can't make it stay after the user hovers over the actual dropdown and not its link. I have tried creating a `:hover` class with the needed display value on the actual dropdown but it appears there is some space when the mouse moves from the link to dropdown so it becomes invisible again before the second `:hover` class has a chance to be applied.

```css
.nav-link:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(201, 49, 49);
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(201, 49, 49);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}

.nav-link:active+.nav-dropdown {
  display: inherit;
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.nav-dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div className="navbar">
  <div className="navbar-elements nav-link">Menu</div>
  <div className="nav-dropdown">Dropdown</div>
  <div className="navbar-elements nav-link">Events</div>
  <div className="navbar-elements nav-link">Reserve</div>
  <div className="navbar-elements">THE MINIMALIST</div>
  <div className="navbar-elements nav-link">Delivery</div>
  <div className="navbar-elements nav-link">About us</div>
  <div className="navbar-elements nav-link">Contacts</div>
</div>
```

I would really prefer to keep it just HTML/CSS if that's possible. Is there a way to achieve desired behavior without lots of refactoring? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use normal HTML than it's `class` and not `className`;

Try to put your `.nav-dropdown` inside the `.nav-link`.

and add on hover effect by targeting `.nav-link:hover .nav-dropdown {}`

```css
.nav-dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(201, 49, 49);
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(201, 49, 49);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-link:hover .nav-dropdown {
  display: inherit;
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-elements nav-link">
    Menu
    <div class="nav-dropdown">Dropdown</div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-elements nav-link">Events</div>
  <div class="navbar-elements nav-link">Reserve</div>
  <div class="navbar-elements">THE MINIMALIST</div>
  <div class="navbar-elements nav-link">Delivery</div>
  <div class="navbar-elements nav-link">About us</div>
  <div class="navbar-elements nav-link">Contacts</div>
</div>
```